# OrderBy date with grqphql in react js

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have a graphql react application with a mongodb that allows users to enter events.  I have a field in the Event model eventStart.  The user selects the date from a date picker and it is currently saved as a string becuase I cannot get it to work with date type.

I am trying to figure out how I can order the events by eventStart date but I cannot figure out how to do it either in the typeDefs and/or resolvers.

My Events TypeDefs are:

```
type Event {
    _id: ID
    eventStyle: String
    eventType: String
    eventName: String
    eventCity: String
    eventState: String
    eventGenInfo: String
    eventWeighInInfo: String
    eventStartDate: String
    eventEndDate: String
    eventStartTime: String
    earlyEntryDeadline: String
    earlyFirstEntryFee: Float
    earlyAddEntryFee: Float
    lateFirstEntryFee: Float
    lateAddEntryFee: Float
    entryDeadline: String
    eventWaiver: String
    judoDivJNov: Boolean
    judoDivJAdv: Boolean
    judoDivSNov: Boolean
    judoDivSAdv: Boolean
    judoDivSOpen: Boolean
    judoDivMNov: Boolean
    judoDivMAdv: Boolean
    judoDivVI: Boolean
    judoDivKata: Boolean
    logo: String
    athleteFirstName: Boolean
    athleteLastName: Boolean
    athleteDOB: Boolean
    athleteAddress1: Boolean
    athleteAddress2: Boolean
    athleteCity: Boolean
    athleteState: Boolean
    athleteEmail: Boolean
    athleteRank: Boolean
    createdBy: String
    slug: String
  }

events: [Event!]!
```

The Event resolvers are:

```
events: async () => {
      let events = await Event.find({});
      return events;
    },
```

I also have the GET_EVENT query on the frontend:

```
export const GET_EVENTS = gql`
  {
    events {
      _id
      eventStyle
      eventType
      eventName
      eventCity
      eventState
      eventGenInfo
      eventStartDate
      slug
    }
  }
`;
```

I've been searching for hours but cannot figure out where or how to handle it.
If I need to change the date back to type: Date in the model I can do that but I just can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As often heppens, I search for hours and even days and after not finding an answer I post a question on here, then find the answer.

I don't know if this is the best way but after converting the eventStartDate back to type: Date in the model then updating the resolver to:

```
events: async () => {
      let events = await Event.find({});

      events.sort((a, b) => a.eventStartDate - b.eventStartDate);

      return events;
    },
```

It's working.  I am definitely open to trying other solutions if anyone has any ides.